# Deploying Azure resource from VS using ResourceMangerTemplates asks to enter the parameters values again even if they exist in the parameters file

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring

I am using an "Azure Resource Group" project in VS to deploy Azure resources (in this case I am trying to deploy a Scheduled Query Rule).

I have two parameters files for deploying on two environments and when using the first parameters file everything works fine. When using the second parameters file it asks me to enter the parameters values again in the PowerShell window.

Why is it doing that? Everything is correct in the second parameters file. I copied its content in the first parameters file (overwriting) and the deployment worked just fine without asking to enter the values again.

Comment: do you observe the same behavior when deploying manually with powershell (probably not). I suspect it has something to do with VS not picking it up

Comment: You are right, deploying from PowerShell doesn't ask for parameters values. It is VS.
Wondering if anyone knows of a workaround.

Comment: Ideally it would ask to enter parameter values for empty parameters. Please double check that part.
Also you may refer this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy) quick start guide that may help.